# Compare the email ID's using Inforatica

Tags: informatica

I wish to compare Email-Id's that are obtained from 2 different sources.

If I have John Smith From Apple and the two email Id's that I have are -

```
Jsmith@apple.com
```

and

```
Johnsmith@apple.com
```

I must determine if the two addresses relate to the same person.

`Inserting` and `Substring` functions are not full-proof.

I want correct answers in my bucket even if all are not covered..!!

I want solution through informatica.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Try and reword your question so that it is easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Are Jsmith@apple.com and Johnsmith@apple.com the same person? How can you tell? Please explain.